# WebConsole and Javascript is disabled when replacing the whole document

Tags: javascript, dom

When I try to replace the whole html document using js, this work causes the page's javascript events to not work. When I put

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML = document.documentElement.innerHTML.replace(/\(\+93\)/g, "(+93)");
```

In the Console then javascript events and triggers dont work.
Actually I see a line of alert in the Firefox's Console:

```
The Web Console logging API (console.log, console.info, console.warn, console.error) has been disabled by a script on this page.
```

How can I get around this problem?

Comment: Why are you doing that to the entire documentElement?

Comment: That's a terrible idea, select the DOM elements directly and modify their content.

Comment: No No No I cant .. webpage that i want to do this on it changes ids of its elements .. it is dynamic .

Comment: You don't have to use IDs for selecting the elements.

Comment: So just choose <body> or  <html> why do this?

Comment: You are not in my situation ! so just imagine you need to do this and you face this problem.

Comment: Alternative approach: iterate over all text nodes and replace the contents of those that contain the string you are looking for.